# Dataframe row duplicated in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to make a data frame containing all information about the vector x. 
Since the last column (minmax) is a vector containing 2 values, my dataframe duplicated its rows!

```
x <- c(4, 10, 3, 30, 2, 5, 20, 12, 25, 9)

somme <- sum(x)
message("Somme: ", somme)

produit <- prod(x)
message("Produits: ", produit)

moyenne <- mean(x)
message("Moyenne: ", moyenne)

variance <- var(x)
message("Variance: ", variance)

ecart_type <- sd(x)
message("Ecart type: ", ecart_type)

minimum <- min(x)
message("Minimum: ", minimum)

maximum <- max(x)
message("Maximum: ", maximum)

# Vector containing min & max

minmax <- c(minimum, maximum)
minmax

recap <- data.frame(somme, produit, moyenne, variance, ecart_type, minimum, maximum, minmax)
recap
```

#### Result (for recap only)

```
  somme   produit moyenne variance ecart_type minimum maximum minmax
1   120 1.944e+09      12       96   9.797959       2      30      2
2   120 1.944e+09      12       96   9.797959       2      30     30
```

#### Expected result

```
  somme   produit moyenne variance ecart_type minimum maximum minmax
1   120 1.944e+09      12       96   9.797959       2      30   2,30
```

Comment: write this in your recap instead: `paste(minmax, collapse = ", ")`

Comment: You can't have a vector in a single "cell" in a data frame. If you want the minmax to appear as a single cell, it will need to be in character format, so change `minmax <- c(minimum, maximum)` to `minmax <- paste(minimum, maximum, sep = ", ")`.